# HTML image and text align top and bottom

Tags: html, css

I use the code below to display an image and some text like `1 2 3 4` right to it. I am new to html and css and while the image part works fine, I'd like the text to be aligned to fill the top and bottom part of the image, like this:

[image]

Same way, if I add more text then to be aligned automatically... Where should I look for this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/christmas-clipart/128/flower-icon.png" />1 2 3 4   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thare is no have simple way to do it.
You can do somthing like this with css line-height or flex box.
But if you just start to learn I will Offering you to wait with it because it is to a more advanced level.

Comment: @MosheHarush except that there is :)

Comment: @Obsidian According to what he said is at the "starting" level.
I'm not sure if you should straighten into a flex that is considered relative to something new and advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**With some CSS Flex Magic**

This is completely scalable and will work no matter what size the image is.

```css
#imgWrap,
#imgWrap ul{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
#imgWrap ul{
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgWrap">
  <img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/christmas-clipart/128/flower-icon.png">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li> 
    <li>2</li> 
    <li>3</li> 
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 but I would remove `flex: 1` on the children and use `justify-content: space-between` on the parent to make it exactly like op's image.

Comment: @MichaelCoker approved and ammended.

Answer (score 0):

**Note : Flex not support in IE9 , IE8 AND IE7,SO I dont use it.**

**Try This :**

```css
#wrapper {

  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;

}

#wrapper:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  content:'';
}

#Number {

  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 130px;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}

.im {

  float: left;
   
}

span {

  display: block;
  height: 28%;
             
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <img class="im" src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/christmas-clipart/128/flower-icon.png">

  <div id="Number">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For keep it simple you can set the image to background and make padding in width of the image:

```css
#imgHolder{
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/christmas-clipart/128/flower-icon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 130px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgHolder">
    1
    <br/>
    2
    <br/>
    3
    <br/>
    4
</div>
```